# Enumerating shortcode attributes in JavaScript

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I'm working on a plugin which uses a shortcode to call a JQuery function, and it requires three aspects to work:

1. The JQuery code + its own code, to be included on the pages it will be used on
2. The HTML element it will work on requires an "id" attribute, in order to reference it
3. A reference/initialization in a `$(document).ready(function())` block

I've already implemented 1 and 2; 1 by using `wp_register_script` and, if the shortcode appears, `wp_print_scripts` to print it; and 2 by making "id" an attribute of my shortcode, which also gets returned, e.g. `[myshortcode id="foo"]` returns `id="foo"`.

The problem is 3.  The initialization is of the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#id").func( {attributes} ); 
     } 
 );
```

I've considered using `wp_localize_script` over a variable for the ID; however, I do not know how many times the shortcode will appear on a given page, and it seems sloppy to register an arbitrary number of otherwise-identical scripts and just hope that the number won't be surpassed.

This seems like it's probably pretty common, but I haven't been able to find anything related by searching.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: So, you will have an html like `<div id="f1"></div><div id="f2"></div>`, and you want to execute `$("#f1, #f2").something()` in the footer?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  And so far, the way that I've implemented that is, e.g. <div [shortcode id="f1"]></table>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2nd, i recommend using the php function `uniqid()`, takes some of the work of user.

For 3rd i think the best way to implement is to keep adding the id's after each shortcode call to a global/static variable in an array & then hook a function to `wp_footer` that reads from this variable to get all the id's & generate the neccessary javascript

For 1st, add this inside the shortcode function-

```
STATIC $flag = false;
if(!$flag) {
    $flag = true;

    // include all your scripts that you want to include in the page only once
    // These statements will be executed once per page load
    // irrespective of how many times shortcode is called.
}
```

Comment: For 3, my understanding of WordPress is that the Right Way (tm) to insert JavaScript is using WordPress functions (i.e. `wp_enqueue_script`/`wp_register_script`) rather than, e.g. `echo`ing it into the page.  The problem with using a WordPress function is that the `wp_enqueue_script' call needs to be done before the content is loaded, so it's impossible to know how many shortcodes and what their IDs are when making that call.

Comment: you're right, the only way to add shortcode specific scripts is to `echo` it directly inside the shortcode content or hook it to `wp_footer`. You'll also need to change the priority in `wp_footer` manually so as to handle dependancies